# Many to many - junction table

Tags: database, database-design, many-to-many

I am doing this design. Users can speak one or more languages (limit five). first language is the native and the others are in order of fluency.

```
user 1 speak 3 languages

    user_id|first language|secondlanguage|thirdlanguage|fourthlanguage| fifthlanguage 
    1        english (1)     franch(2)    portuguese (3)      null           null
```

[image]

What do you think about this scheme?
Sounds a bit strange or it is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer on this one is that it really depends.  Relational purists will say this is a repeating group and this is a terrible design, while the quick-and-dirty crowd will say, "if you're only ever going to support 5 languages, then do it".  But, really - how can you be sure you'd only support 5 languages forever and always?  And what sorts of queries will you be doing?  Imagine you want to find all the people who speak English - your query will be:

```
select * from single_user_has_spoken_languages where lang1 = @englishID or lang2 = @englishID or... etc
```

If you want to find people that speak both English and French, then your where clause grows again.  And every single query will have to change if you ever add a 6th language.

Consider the alternative:

```
select distinct UserID from single_user_has_spoken_languages where langID = @englishID
```

Once you stop and think about how your queries will work, good design begins to become much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I would normalize out the languages.

So, for example (non-key columns omitted for brevity):

```
Language Table
id:  INT

Single_User Table
id:  INT

User_Language Table
user_id: INT
language_id: INT
language_num:  SMALLINT
```

You can put unique constraints on both user_id, language_id as well as user_id, language_num to ensure no duplicates.  You can also put a check constraint on language_num to be between 1 and 5 to ensure only 5 languages are selected.

You can also choose to add a surrogate key which would make referencing rows easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "denormalized" form of the "correct" or "normaised" design, which would have a separate table to store languages that had a column for the fluency order, ie:

```
Table User: User_ud, name, etc
Table Language: user_id, fluency, name
```

Your approach is usually used for performance reasons, but is usually to be avoided at the design stage.

Consider how your design would handle adding more language slots, or storing *how well* the language was spoken. The normalized design can handle this easily. You approach can not.